# Expressing values of irrationals in the form of fractions

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Let's have the following sequence of fractions: $\frac{24}{17}, \frac{816}{577}, \frac{941664}{665857}, ?$.

What is the next fraction in this sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next one is

> $\frac{1254027132096}{886731088897}$.

This is best explained

> [here](http://oeis.org/A001601). They appear to be related to Newton's method of calculation of $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I got the same answer. For those who have a hard time understanding the link posted by @WhatsUp, the next denominator in the pattern seems to be the denominator^2 times 2 minus 1. And for the numerator, you multiply the denominator by ~1.41421356237 to calculate.

Comment: The formula is $\frac{2ab}{(a^2)/2+b^2}$.